# Detection of grid points from scanned prints in Python / OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have scanned documents which are printed by different inkjet-printers (Epson, HP, Canon and so on). Each photo has a very high quality (like 1,6GB) and you can zoom in and see the halftone of the picture which is using a frequency modulation.

My task is to do a feature extraction based on the grid dots, patterns of the grid, distance of the dots etc.

The relevant features are the size of these dots (each printers print different size of these dots - have to calculate the mean and standard deviation).

Later I will have to train a model with ML and the trained model should classify a print to a specific printer (so basically this print belongs to printer XYZ).

But for now I am struggling with the feature engineering already and the pre processing stuffs as this is my first computer-vision project actually and I am not so familar with opencv.

I have an idea and my plan is to a binary transformation with opencv of the images to determine the edges (Edge detection) via Sobel or Prewitt filter or whatsoever.
So I think I have to put some blur and then a edge detection maybe?

I am not sure if this is the right approach, so that's why I ask here, what do you think?
I would be happy if you can give me some hints or steps for the best or a good approach.

Comment: You could threshold on color using cv2.inRange(). Pick one color at a time. Then potentially use cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats() to find all the isolated regions and their sizes. Then you can get the average size and standard deviation for all the regions. Alternately, after thresholding, you could get the contours of each isolated region and get the sizes from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way in Python/OpenCV.

Threshold on color using cv2.inRange(). In this case I will threshold on the blue dots. Then get all the external contours to find all the isolated regions. From the contours, compute the equivalent circular diameters. Then compute the average and standard deviations.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

img = cv2.imread("color_dots.png")

# threshold on blue color
lower = (190,150,100)
upper = (255,255,170)
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# get external contours
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
count = len(contours)

sum = 0
sum2 = 0
for cntr in contours:
    # get area from contours and then diameters of equivalent circles
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    # area = pi*radius**2 = pi*(diameter/2)**2 = (pi/4)*diameter**2
    # diameter = sqrt(4*area/pi) = 2*sqrt(area/pi)
    diameter = 2 * math.sqrt(area/math.pi)
    sum = sum + diameter
    sum2 = sum2 + diameter * diameter

# compute average2 (mean)
average = sum/count
average2 = sum2/count

# compute standard deviation
variance = average2 - average*average
standard_deviation = math.sqrt(variance)

# print results
print("average:", average)
print("std_dev:", standard_deviation)

# save result
cv2.imwrite("color_dots_blue_threshold.png",thresh)

# display result
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Results:

```
average: 3.0747726858108635
std_dev: 0.541288251281962
```

Comment: Wow awesome! Thank you! I didn't know that it's better to seperate into each color (blue, yellow, cyan)... What is also interesting, is the average distances between the dots, how can I achieve that? Is it possible to calculate the distances with opencv?

Comment: The brute force way would be to get the centroids from the contours and  compute the distances from each point to every other point. Then find the shortest distant for each.

Comment: These may be of interest: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28207/finding-the-closest-point-to-a-list-of-points/28210#28210 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022381/how-do-i-connect-closest-points-together-using-opencv/51030717. But this may be the best. It computes all distances between two arrays. You them look for the minimum output for a given input position in the array. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html

Comment: Thanks again! I am going to threshold the other dots as well and have a question about the lower and upper threshold in your example: How can I determine the value like you did for the color blue? `lower = (190, 150, 100)` and `upper = (255, 255, 170)`

Comment: I measured some blue values in other tools and made a first estimate of the range. Then just trial and adjust until the black/white dots became about the right size to match the input. Visual checks with cv2.imshow().